# PHP_Beautifier - Fatal Error - require PEAR.php

Tags: php, macos, terminal, pear, php-beautifier

I have installed pear and php_beautifier with sudo...

From what I've read I should be able to format code with the command

```
php_beautifier x.php
```

But when I try to do this I get this error:

```
Warning: require_once(PEAR.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/philip/pear/bin/php_beautifier on line 37

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PEAR.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/philip/pear/bin/php_beautifier on line 37
```

I have looked at the php_beautifier.php code and I don't know what's wrong. Line 37:

```
require_once 'PEAR.php';
```

and the file is in the same dir as pear.php?

Comment: @SalmanA Ahh my bad, I have pear but not pear.php in my folder.. Is it safe to just copy a version of pear and name it pear.php in the same folder?

Comment: Perhaps you do not have to. Do a `php -i > phpinfo.txt`, open the file and note down the value for `include_path`. If it contains valid `/path/to/the/folder/that/contains/PEAR.php` then problem is somewhere else. Otherwise you just need to add/edit the path in the php.ini file.

Comment: @SalmanA - I found that all my files that I needed was in .../pear/share/pear/

I just included that in php.ini and it worked :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, the path to PEAR directory should be specified in [`include_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) directive in php.ini. This allows you to include PEAR core and packages in your code easily, for example:

```
require_once 'PEAR.php';
require_once 'Console/Getopt.php';
```

Otherwise, you will have to specify full path to the PEAR directory which makes your code less portable:

```
require_once '/usr/share/pear/PEAR.php';
require_once '/usr/share/pear/Console/Getopt.php';
```

To probe the *effective value* of the `include_path` directive, use the `phpinfo()` function. If it does not contain the path to PEAR installation, use:

```
# UNIX
include_path = ".:/path/to/pear"
# Windows
include_path = ".;C:\path\to\pear"
```

More detailed and step-by-step [instructions can be found here](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php).

Answer (score 0):

Open /private/etc/php.ini

And replace this line (796):

```
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
```

to:

```
include_path = "/usr/lib/php/pear"
```

Answer (score 0):

First check pear is installed with command:

```
pear
```

If not installed use this command to install it:

```
sudo apt install php-pear
```